# How shorten lambda function according to PEP8?

Tags: python-3.x, pep8

I want to shorten the function, but I can not figure out how to do it.

String too long. How to fix this code?

```
def get_closest_bar(data, user_latitude, user_longitude):
    return min(
        data['features'],
        key=lambda x: sqrt((x['geometry']['coordinates'][1] - user_latitude)**2 + (x['geometry']['coordinates'][0] - user_longitude)**2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
def get_closest_bar(data, user_latitude, user_longitude):
    return min(
        data['features'],
        key=lambda x: sqrt(
            (x['geometry']['coordinates'][1] - user_latitude) ** 2 + 
            (x['geometry']['coordinates'][0] - user_longitude) ** 2))
```

I use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) as my IDE.  I added only one thing to the above automatic reformatting that PyCharm did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets `()` for for multi line lambdas. This is discouraged and you should have a function that will replace the lambda.

```
# USE

def get_closest_bar(data, user_latitude, user_longitude):
    def key(x):
        return (
            sqrt((x['geometry']['coordinates'][1] - user_latitude)**2 + 
            (x['geometry']['coordinates'][0] - user_longitude)**2)
        )
    return min(data['features'], key=key)

# INSTEAD OF 

def get_closest_bar(data, user_latitude, user_longitude):
    key = lambda x: (
        sqrt((x['geometry']['coordinates'][1] - user_latitude)**2 + 
        (x['geometry']['coordinates'][0] - user_longitude)**2)
    )
    return min(data['features'], key=key)
```